# Calculating new value in increased serving size

Tags: divisibility, ratio

This is probably going to sound like a very stupid question but I'm more of a designer than a maths person unfortunately.

I'm just trying to work out how I'd get a new weight of an ingredient for a serving size when I know that current weight for a serving.

So I have 3000mg of Ingredient "A" in a 5.1gram serving. I need to work out how much I have in an 8gram serving.

I thought it was just a case of (3000 / x) * 8 = value But obviously the more I increase x the less the value is.

As i said probably a really easy question but I'm struggling :)

Comment: @close-voter..  seriously?  This question is unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple different ways to set it up.  Here's one.
$$\dfrac{3000 \text{ mg}}{5.1 \text{ gram}} = \dfrac{x \text{ mg}}{8 \text{ gram}}$$
Solve for $x$ by multiplying both sides by $8$.
$$x = \frac{3000}{5.1} \cdot 8 \approx 4705.88 \text{ mg}$$

Comment: This is the figure I'd come up with, so my sums were right :) - Now I think about it it makes total sense. I'd just got myself quite confused. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The proportions must stay the same, so

$$
\frac{x}{3000} = \frac{8}{5.1} .
$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have x miligram of ingredient in 8 gram of food, then using law of proportions:

$$\frac{x}{8} = \frac{3000}{5.1} $$
$$\frac{x}{3000} = \frac{8}{5.1} $$
From here $x$ comes out to be $4705.8823$